# Unable to install same apps on 1 device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to install 2 same apps on 1 device for testing. What should i change in the plist in order to install the same apps on 1 device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in info.plst file change the Bundle identifier.

Comment: Ya Mangal is right as well.Hey Mangal do help the Parvind as well.He needs your help in finding someone.....

Comment: He is just using hand for that purpose man.....Its stack overflow..let him know over FB

Comment: Ya Mangal Pandey saahab we are in the same .company

Answer (score 0):

Mangal is right as well.
Even you can change the product name for this as well  to achieve the same thing.

That will help you...as well