# Have 2 of the same app on 1 phone?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, icloud

I have an app on the App Store and I downloaded it onto my phone. Now, I want to integrate iCloud and Push Notification into this app. If I open Xcode and run it on the same device, it overwrites the App Store app. My goal is to have 2 versions of this 1 app on my phone: 1 from the App Store and 1 from Xcode for development purposes.

I have read two articles and can't come up with a solution:

[Unable to install same apps on 1 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674654/unable-to-install-same-apps-on-1-device)

[Create Multiple Targets/Apps for 1 Xcode Project](http://samwize.com/2014/05/22/create-multiple-targets-slash-apps-for-1-xcode-project/)

By changing the Bundle Identifier, it is possible based on the article above. But will there be a problem when testing iCloud and push notifications? The App ID and what is in iTunes Connect relies on the Bindle Identifier and when testing iCloud and push notifications, I need iTunes Connect. So this is the problem from what I see.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Purely FTR .. why do you wish to do this. (It might help figure a way to do it.)  Cheers ...

Comment: @JoeBlow It's a note-taking app and I like using my own app so I don't want to lose the data while testing. For example, if I need to delete the app and reinstall it just for testing purposes, everything will be gone. I also don't want to spend money and own two devices.

Comment: Got it.  Tough problem!  I've been in that situation!!  I guess ideally the info could be saved to the cloud (say parse.com or the like)

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately I don't know how to do that yet. Do you think there's any other way or does changing the Bundle Identifier work? Not sure since I never tried testing iCloud or push notifications with iTunes Connect.

Comment: @JoeBlow What if I change the Bundle Identifier to for example "com.company.TEST" and use this for myself. Then I use the original bundle Identifier that is used for the App Store for development, for example "com.company.ORIGINAL." I won't get updates from the App Store, but do you think this is a good idea? But then I don't think iCloud will work my for personal use.

Comment: correct. you WONT lose your data but the app WILL NOT work properly  :O

Comment: @JoeBlow So besides your suggestion, the only other way might be to create 2 App Ids, 2 Bundle Identifiers, 2 apps on iTunes Connect (1 for testing and 1 on the App Store) ----- is this correct?

Comment: Um, as ar as I know, yes...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new bundle ID (say with an added .CLONE suffix).  Use Xcode to build your App Store submitted code (from your source repository) identical except built using this new bundle ID.  Install it side-by-side with the original App Store app (identical source code).

Then manually copy your notes out of your App Store app and paste them into the new Clone app.  You can use Xcode to back up the new clone app's sandbox.  (There might also be tools that are able to pull you app's notes DB out of an unencrypted iTunes backup, if you make or have such.)

Then delete your App Store app (if needed) and install any new version as needed for development and testing using the original bundle ID for iCloud testing.

Your real non-test data will reside in the Clone of your earlier App Store app during development.  You can copy it back into the App Store submission when done.